# Use generator function with yield inside a class in ES2015 using KoaJS

Tags: node.js, koa, monk, ecmascript-6

I’m trying to call a generator function inside a class from the constructor, it runs but nothing happens (my console.log are not printing) as if the generator function is never called.

### Update #1:

Here's an updated version of my code.  I am able to access my findOne function with the next() function, but since I wrapped "users" with co-monk, I tough there was no need to call it.  I'm still not sure why I need to call next(0) function 2 times to jump over the yield call.

Therefore, I'm now getting undefined when I print the output of "userData".

If my issue is related to understand on how yield works, maybe pointing me to direction could help me.  I tried using generator functions with yield calls apart from a class and it worked perfectly fine with monk/co-monk.

### Update #2:

I should also mention that I'm using babel6 for transcript.

```
"use strict";

var monk = require("monk");
var wrap = require("co-monk");
var db = monk("localhost/test");
var users = wrap(db.get("users"));

class User {

    constructor(user) {
        if (typeof user == "object") {

            var findUser = this.findOne(user.id);
            findUser.next();
            findUser.next();

            if(findUser != null){
                this._user = user;
            }

        }
        else {
            console.error("user parameter is not an oject");
            return false;
        }
    }

    *findOne(id) {

        var userData = yield users.findOne({_id: id});

        console.log(userData); // Getting undefined

        this._user = userData;

    };


}

var _user = new User({id : "1234"});
console.log(_user);

export default User;
```

Comment: `this.findOne*(id);` is a syntax error.

Comment: My bad, I made a typo before posting this.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the docs for `co-monk` are a bit vague, but looking at the [one test it has](https://github.com/tj/co-monk/blob/master/test/index.js), it needs to be used within `co`.

```
var co = require("co");

// rest of your code

  findOne(id) {
    return co(function* () {
      var userData = yield users.findOne({_id: id});
      console.log(userData); // Getting undefined
      this._user = userData;
    });
  };
```

What it won't allow you to do is seamlessly transition async code back into sync code, so `this.findOne()` will return a promise. As a result, your `User` object may not be populated immediately after called `new User({id : "1234"})`.

Comment: Thank you for you'r kind reply.  What I did finally, i got out the generator function out of my class, and inside findOne function, i returned a promise from monk db call.  I then used generator function with yield call from the contoller function into this.body response.  It's way cleaner that way.  Here my upvote for you annnnnnnnnnnnnnnd my 5o points bounty since you were the only one to answer me ;-) thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

tried with the lib co and it worked.

It looks like co-monk is broken inside a generator function inside a class at this moment.

so here's what worked for me :

```
"use strict";

var monk = require("monk");
//var wrap = require("co-monk");
var db = monk("localhost/test");
var users = (db.get("users"));
var co = require('co');

class User {

    constructor(user) {
        if (typeof user == "object") {
            var findUser = this.findOne(user.id);
            this._user = user;
        }
        else {
            console.error("The user params is not an object");
        }
    }

    findOne(id) {

        co(function* () {
            return yield users.findOne({_id: id});
        }).then(function (val) {
            console.log(val);
        }, function (err) {
            console.error(err.stack);
        });

    };
}
```